# Как в Subversion узнать все комиты пользователя в заданный модуль?

Tags: svn, контроль-версий

Например, есть maven-модуль по сути одна из папок в структуре проекта. Как вывести список всех комитов затрагивающих эту папку и можно ли как-то отфильтровать этот список по имени пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правой кнопкой на папке, куда сделан checkout модуля, show log, там слева сверху ввести имя автора, ткнуть на лупу и снять пометку со всех пунктов кроме Автор. Нет?